# Print only two lines

Tags: regex, optimization, html-email, clipping, template-toolkit

I am making a html email template, and I am looking for a solution to only output text over two lines in the email. I cant find a easy solution to this and i am about to write a complex regex that takes upper-case and special characters in consideration. At the moment i have this  regex that keeps the 160 first characters and removes the rest.

```
[% IF doc.text.length > 160 %][% doc.text.replace('(?<=.{160}).*', '') %]...[% ELSE %][% doc.text %][% END %]
```

Is there any easier solution to only print out text over 2 lines?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `textarea` in the table cell to truncate the text:

```
 <td>
   <textarea rows="2" readonly>
    ...
    ...
    ...
   </textarea>
 </td>
```

Comment: Haven't had the time to test this, but I like your solution very much.